# Dispatcher Dilemma - How To Dispatch Properly?

Tags: wpf

I have read articles about Dispatcher in WPF but none was really very explaining the behaviour of Dispatcher very well. So my question to you guys is what does Dispatcher do exactly except keeping a queue of tasks and executing them by their priorities? What does the queue look alike? If I put 3 tasks in in sequence with priority "normal", and then subsequently one task with priority "send". Which will be executed first? In what order will the 3 tasks with priority normal be executed? Are there some really good tutorial about Dispatcher or some prove of concepts you guys would like to share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Dispatcher` is effectively just the message pump for WPF applications.

Unlike the traditional windows message pump, it does have a priority built in, so it acts like a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) instead of a traditional (first in, first out) queue.

If you dispatch a message with a priority of `Send`, it will get processed before other operations with other priorities, such as `Normal`.  You can see the list of priorities, as well as their values, in the [`DispatcherPriority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) help.  Higher priority messages are always processed prior to lower priority messages (which aren't already being handled).

As for your specific questions:

> So my question to you guys is what does Dispatcher do exactly except keeping a queue of tasks and executing them by their priorities?

It handles windows messages, and processes them, just like the normal windows message pump in a traditional Win32 or Windows Forms application.  The prioritized queue is built in order to process user messages in addition to standard windows messages, with a priority built in.

> What does the queue look alike?

It's effectively a priority queue.

> If I put 3 tasks in in sequence with priority "normal", and then subsequently one task with priority "send". Which will be executed first?

It depends.  If there is other work happening at the time, the `Send` task will process first.  If no other work is occurring, the `Normal` task may get executed before you submit the `Send` task, in which case the order will change.  The `Send` task will get executed as soon as possible, however.

> In what order will the 3 tasks with priority normal be executed?

These will get executed in the same order in which they are dispatched.

Comment: Thank you Reed Copsey. I have one more question to you. What is ContextLayoutManager. It seems to be something like dispatcher or something using Dispatcher in WPF. Futhermore if I call the Dispatcher to BeginInvoke(..) a method with the priority "normal" and that method is this.InvalidateMeasure(). Will only the InvalidateMeasure(), which sets furthermore the measure dirty flag to true, be executed without actually measure(), or will bee the InvalidateMeasure() and measure() combined to the same task and will be executed together with normal priority?

Comment: @hedgehog - This is a bit much for a comment (really completely new questions) - The `ContextLayoutManager` is an internal class used to handle layout issues.  If you dispatch `InvalidateMeasure()`, it will only invalidate in that "task" - the actual measure message will happen later.

Comment: I have tested it out. Seems the InvalidateMeasure() and measure() will be combined to one and executed together. I dont know why is that so. Futhermore I would like to open a new chat to discuss the ContextLayoutManager, just I dont know how to create a new chat channel.

Comment: @hedgehog You should just ask your question about it as a new question (and close this one).  The Measure call should happen immediately after the InvalidateMeasure call, so it may "appear" to be together, but only your code will get executed in your dispatched operation.

Comment: Interesting because I did a demo example where I am inside a measureoverride of a completely other control and i call inside Dispatcher.BeginInvoke the InvalidateMeasure of another control. The another controls measure does get executed automatically and steals first controls measuring. Its confusing.. Yes, i closed this question and I would like to open a chat instead new question to talk about measuing in wpf. How do i create a new chat event?

Comment: seems I need some kind of privilege to create a new chat room. Sad :-(